# I can't change the disk layout of an installed Linux system

Tags: linux, partitioning, debian, initrd

I have a Debian Jessie system with LVM2 layer. By a mistake, I had installed this system with many partitions (root, usr, home, var,...). Now, I run out of disk space for `usr` and `var` partitions, even there is a plenty of space in the `home` partition.

I decided to change the disk layout. First, I copied all files (`bin`, `usr`, `var`, ...) into the `home` partition. I created a symbolic link to show `home -> .` in `home` partition. So, I thought that if I could mount `home` partition as `/` partition, then everything should work without notice.

I had `fstab` like this:

```
/dev/mapper/cca--erik--vg-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=49819ee7-f63b-4eb9-b83e-6e2cf868df62 /boot           ext2    defaults        0       2
/dev/mapper/cca--erik--vg-home /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
/dev/mapper/cca--erik--vg-tmp /tmp            ext4    defaults        0       2
/dev/mapper/cca--erik--vg-usr /usr            ext4    defaults        0       2
/dev/mapper/cca--erik--vg-var /var            ext4    defaults        0       2
#/home/var /var none bind 
/dev/mapper/cca--erik--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/sr0        /media/cdrom0   udf,iso9660 user,noauto     0       0
```

I changed it like this:

```
/dev/mapper/cca--erik--vg-home /           ext4    errors=remount-ro        0       1
/dev/mapper/cca--erik--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/sr0        /media/cdrom0   udf,iso9660 user,noauto     0       0
```

Similarly, I changed the `grub` entry from:

```
    linux   /vmlinuz-3.13-1-amd64 root=/dev/mapper/cca--erik--vg-root ro  quiet ipv6.disable=1
```

to:

```
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13-1-amd64 root=/dev/mapper/cca--erik--vg-home ro  quiet ipv6.disable=1
```

but there is no success. The initrd still insist on mounting `/dev/mapper/cca--erik--vg-root` as `/`. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I figured out a series of mistakes I did.

First, here is the last status I achieved:

```
ceremcem@cca-erik:ceremcem$ df -h
Filesystem                      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/cca--erik--vg-home  876G  817G   15G  99% /
udev                             10M     0   10M   0% /dev
tmpfs                           790M  788K  789M   1% /run
tmpfs                           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                           4.7G  108K  4.7G   1% /run/shm
none                            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
ceremcem@cca-erik:ceremcem$ ls /
bin          dev         lib         media       owncloud  srv         var
boot         etc         lib32       mnt         proc      sys         vmlinuz
        guest       lib64       nginx-body  root      tmp
ceremcem     home        libx32      nginx-root  run       tmp-backup
debian-root  initrd.img  lost+found  opt         sbin      usr
ceremcem@cca-erik:ceremcem$
```

Yes, I edited the `/etc/fstab` file before, but actually I edited a file in the `/dev/mapper/cca--erik--vg-root` lvm partition. Since I told kernel via boot parameters: "hey, from now on your root is `/dev/mapper/cca--erik--vg-home`" it mounts the `...-vg-home` lvm partition as `/`, where the `etc/fstab` file stayed untouched. I simply edited that file (`/home/etc/fstab`) and system booted as intended.

(actually there was a kernel panic situation but as I figured out, I didn't create `/home/dev` directory (even an empty one). so I got created this and the other directories which are required; system booted up. )